# Search database

Tags: python, database, search

Furthering my study of database use in python, I have come up with the following code based on Bryan Moyles excellent example:

```
from os   import system as cmd
from time import sleep  as sleep
try:
    from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite
except ImportError:
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite

class search_db:
    def __init__(self, db, name):
        self.db = db_connection
        self.name = name
        self.dbc = self.db.cursor()

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        self.dbc.execute("select * from %s limit %s, 1" % (self.name, item))
        return self.dbc.fetchone()

def search():
    customer_id  = []
    customer_ids = search_db(db_connection, "customers")
    for i in range(10000):
        if not "None" in str(customer_ids[i]): customer_id.append(customer_ids[i])
    return customer_id

## init ##
db_name = 'customers'
db_connection = sqlite.connect('program.db')
db_curs = db_connection.cursor()

search()
```

Sure, it's nothing fantastic, and I know I could probably optimise it a tad more; but as you can see, I've been trying hard to figure out how to search the database. I managed to retrieve entries that contain information in the database, which pulls out an entry number. I was thinking of using if loops to search the appended list values for a "GGS-*number*" entry, then using regular expressions to extract the line number - then printing the information relevant to the customer that the GGS number applies to. Has anyone got any ideas how I could do this in a better way? Also, I have a for i in range(10000), is there a more optimised form of this?

Comment: I'd have to copy and past and execute to see what you're doing. This is not what Stack Overflow is for. Please post less code with **one** quesiton, we'll be happy to help.

Comment: @Shep Done :) Stripped as much as I can of it, though, as far as I can tell; I am only asking one question.

Comment: Hey, the code looks much better. I'm a little worried about the "so far as I can tell; I am only asking one question", though. I count two. But either way the important thing is that _you_ know what questions you're asking. If you're confused about what you're asking, we probably will be too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is all intended to retrieve the contents of the table "customers", you are doing it wrong. SELECT will give you a table with no gaps; so if the only IDs in use are 10 and 101, your query results will have length 2 and contain the two existing records in rows 0 and 1. It looks like you're trying to skip over empty records, but there aren't any.

But you're making this much too complicated; you've chosen the wrong example to emulate. What you have runs a SELECT query that returns the n'th row from a table, wrapped into a class that allows you to pretend you're dealing with a very slow array. Ditch it and start over.

If you want the entire contents of the `customers` table, use a single query and retrieve them with `fetchall()`:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('program.db')
curs = conn.cursor()
ro = curs.execute('select * from customers')
customers = ro.fetchall()
```

If you need to fetch a particular record, let the database handle that by adding a `WHERE` clause to the query. Almost always you retrieve records by ID (or other attributes), not by their position in the table.

My advice: Keep the python/sqlite scaffolding minimal. Set up a connection, run a query,  fetch the results one by one or all together. That's all. And `curs.rowcount` to find out how many result rows there are before fetching them. Everything else is done more simply and efficiently by an appropriate SQL command. So read up on SQL, not on python's libraries.

Comment: Thank you very much! That halved the runtime of commands in my program, and I've just taken the w3schools SQL tutorial; and understand what your code does. Thank you ! :)